# Javascript code to clean incoming JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, excel, import

I had an Indie programmer write some code to generate a JSON file from the columns in Excel in a macro.  The code works, however occasionally I get invisible char that blow up the JSON parser in my program.  I would like to know if javascript offers the ability to process a string and remove or replace invisible and non printable char in my string?

I am trying to reach the Indie developer to see if this could be done as well from Excel more easily but at the moment he's not reachable.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know what this character is, eg. the hex value?

Comment: This particular character is 120 hex value I believe.  So that I don't have to worry about it however, I'm wondering if I should approach this by only allowing A-z, numerics, and perhaps a few common char like '?' and '/'. ???

Comment: Yes, JavaScript has a replace method with which you can replace any character in a string: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace.